# MongoDb showing connections form Non-Whitelisted IP Address

Tags: mongodb

So i have a M10 instance running along with proper network access rules being setup. When I opened up my mongoshell to check the active connections, this is the output i get :

```
{                                                                                                                               
  "TOTAL_CONNECTION_COUNT" : 96,                                                                                          
  "Internal" : 46,                                                                                                        
  "192.168.254.185" : 16,                                                                                                 
  "192.168.253.242" : 10,                                                                                                 
  "MY PRODUCTION IP 3" : 2,                                                                                                    
  "MY PRODUCTION IP 2" : 13,                                                                                                  
  "MY PRODUCTION IP 1 " : 9                                                                                            }
```

What I am confused about is the two IPs listed below

```
"192.168.254.185" : 16,                                                                                                 "192.168.253.242" : 10,
```

These are not my internal IPs and not whitelisted in mongodb either, so how come these two seem to have connections ? Are these some internal mongodb IPs that I am not taking into account ?

Comment: Look at the server log to see metadata associated with those connections.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I checked the logs for the IP's i was doubtful about and this is the result :

Successfully authenticated as principal __system on local from client 192.168.253.242:32830"

The other one is from somethign called this :

MongoDB Automation Agent v10.18.3.6582 

Any idea about these ?

Comment: Update the question please.